# Unable to connect using Notepad++ plugin NppFTP

Tags: ftp, notepad++

This is the NppFTP output:

```
Connecting
-> Quit  
Unable to connect
Disconnected
```

I had no issues connecting via Putty and WinSCP. Any solutions?

Comment: I also turned off the firewall. No result.

Comment: Is it possible that the remote server is running SFTP (or FTPS), not FTP?  What port do you have `NppFTP` configured to connect to?

Comment: I've tried FTP and SFTP. Also changed port between 22 and 21, even increased timeout but got the same result. I believe its because of some sort of server restrictions because I try to connect to my university server. Maybe NppFTP connection is considered to be unsecure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed ftp service in your remote Linux host.

You can use command `vsftpd -version` to check if you have installed it.

If not, you need to install ftp service first by command `sudo apt-get install vsftpd` (on Ubuntu).